# How to pass values from one page to other page by javascript and get the passed value in the other page using php?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to pass a value from one page to other page when the user clicks on a link.

For example

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.parent.loadFrame('bloodbankFacilities/specialtyDataTable.php',this.innerHTML);">Blood Bank Facilities </a>
```

above is the the link i have to redirect the user to specialityDataTable.php

I want to pass a text value to specialityDataTable.php when the user clicks the link and get the value in specialityDataTable.php by using php GET method and echo it.

I was doing this before, but i forgot how to do it :( .

```
function loadFrame(url,anchorText){
            //alert(url);
            if(document.getElementById(url)){               
                if(hasClassName(document.getElementById(url),"selectedTabHead")){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    changeTab(url,document.getElementById(url));
                    return false;
                }
            }

            iframeId = "ifr_"+url;


            var iframeElem = getElementsByClass("bodyFrame");

            for(var i=0;i<iframeElem.length;i++){
              iframeElem[i].style.display = 'none';                
            }

            if(!document.getElementById(iframeId)){
                var elt = document.createElement("iframe");
                elt.setAttribute("class","bodyFrame");
                elt.setAttribute("id",iframeId);
                elt.setAttribute("onload","iframeReload();");
                document.getElementById('content').appendChild(elt);
            }
            document.getElementById("loadr").style.display = 'block';     
                document.getElementById(iframeId).style.display = 'block'
                document.getElementById(iframeId).src = url;            

            var elements = getElementsByClass("tabHead",document.getElementById("tabStrip"));

            for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
                if(hasClassName(elements[i],"selectedTabHead")){
                    removeClassName(elements[i],"selectedTabHead");
                }
            }
            var elt = document.createElement("span");
            elt.setAttribute("class","tabHead selectedTabHead");
            elt.setAttribute("id",url);
            elt.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0);'  onclick=changeTab('"+url+"',this.parentNode)>"+anchorText+"</a> <b onclick='removeTab(this.parentNode.id)'>x</b>";

            if(elements.length == 0){
                document.getElementById("tabStrip").appendChild(elt);
            }
            else{                
                document.getElementById("tabStrip").insertBefore(elt,elements[0]);
            }
            var tabCookie =  document.getElementById("tabStrip").innerHTML;
            setCookie("<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'] ?>",tabCookie);
            setWidth();
            //autoHeight();
        };


        function loadFullScreen(url){
            url = "<?php echo ROOT_PATH; ?>"+"full.php?q="+url;
            jsPopUp(url,800,1000);

        }


        function changeTab(url,obj){
           // document.getElementById("loadr").style.display = 'block';            
            parentnode = document.getElementById("tabStrip");
            var elements = getElementsByClass("tabHead",parentnode);

            for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
                if(hasClassName(elements[i],"selectedTabHead")){
                    removeClassName(elements[i],"selectedTabHead");
                }
            }

            addClassName(obj,"selectedTabHead");

           // document.getElementById("bodyFrame").src = url;
            iframeId = "ifr_"+url;


            var iframeElem = getElementsByClass("bodyFrame");

            for(var i=0;i<iframeElem.length;i++){
              iframeElem[i].style.display = 'none';                
            }
            //alert(document.getElementById(iframeId));
            if(!document.getElementById(iframeId)){
                var elt = document.createElement("iframe");
                elt.setAttribute("class","bodyFrame");
                elt.setAttribute("id",iframeId);
                elt.setAttribute("onload","iframeReload();");
                document.getElementById('content').appendChild(elt);

            }

                document.getElementById(iframeId).style.display = 'block'


        };
```

Comment: Can you provide the definition (code) of the function `window.parent.loadFrame()` ?

Comment: the load frame function is now added as u asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this just means you have to add the variable to the url..

```
bloodbankFacilities/specialtyDataTable.php?variable=value
```

Comment: yeah...exactly what i was thinking. Thanks Evert, and one more doubt, if i pass a variable like this, i can just get it by using GET from the redirected file(in this case, specialtyDataTable.php) right ?

Comment: @Bala.C: That's not called redirection, but you can get (`$_GET`) it, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass values with get method using jquery or ajax or simple link tag and then you can get values via php also with many ways like file_get_contents or session variable or storing in db.